# db4o loses track of objects on Android

Tags: java, android, db4o

I'm making my first android application and I'm (trying to) use a db4o database.

In general it is structured like this: You have a 'Person' class (with some inheritance to differentiate between 'boss', 'employee', 'intern',... but that doesn't really matter here I guess).
You also have the 'Task'-class. A 'Task' object has (among other attributes) an ArrayList with Persons. A task can exist without persons assigned, and vice versa.

The problem I'm having is that db4o doesn't seem to keep track of my objects. So when I try to attach a Person (loaded from the database with a query) to a Task, the Person gets duplicated.
So for now I've solved this by doing a QBE on the Person object, and adding the returned object to the Task. But this seems very wrong?

So somewhere the reference to my object is lost...
I'm keeping the database connection open the whole time (only closing it onDestroy).

This is a sample action: 
I have an activity in which I fill in some attributes for the Task, and then I use an ActivityForResult in which I select (and return) the Person-object (trough an intent) from a ListView. Then back in the first activity I want to link and save them.

The objects I'm passing in the intent are Serializable, not Parcelable, I don't know if that matters much besides the 'performance hit'?

I'm willing to post some code, but I have no idea what part of the code could be helpful to identify the problem?

Code I think is relevant:

**AddTask Activity:**

(this is in onCreate)

```
Db4oHelper db4oHelper = new Db4oHelper(context);
db=db4oHelper.db();

(...)

Button AddButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Addbutton);
AddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent pickUserIntent = new Intent(context,PickUser.class);
        startActivityForResult(pickUserIntent,1);
    }
});
```

and:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        ArrayList<Person> personList_local = (ArrayList<Person>)
            data.getSerializableExtra("PERSONS");
    ArrayList<Person> personList_db=new ArrayList<Person>();
    for (Person p:personList_local){
        personList_db.add((Person)helper.listResultToArray(db.queryByExample(po)).get(0));
    }
    Task t = new Task("Description",personList_db);
    db.store(t);
        db.commit();
    }
}
```

The helper class with listResultToArray is just a simple iteration for-loop that puts the items of the ObjectSet, returned by the database, into an ArrayList, required for the listview.

**PickUser Activity:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    persons_sel=new ArrayList<Person>();
    Db4oHelper db4oHelper = new Db4oHelper(context);
    db=db4oHelper.db();
    persons_all=helper.listResultToArray(db.query(Person.class));

    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    this.adapter = new PersonAdapter(this, R.layout.row_checkbox, persons_all);
    setListAdapter(this.adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {


            Person p = (Person) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            CheckBox check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            if (!person_sel.remove(p)) { 
                person_sel.add(p);
                check.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                check.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
    Button SubmitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
    SubmitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (persons_sel.size()>0){
             Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
             returnIntent.putExtra("PERSONS", persons_sel); 
             setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent); 
             finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                          "You must select at least something!", 
                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private class PersonAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person> {

    private ArrayList<Person> items;

    public PersonAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<Person> items) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.row_checkbox, null);
        }
        Person p = items.get(position);
        if (p != null) {
            TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.toptext);
            if (tt != null) {
                tt.setText(p.toString());
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the relevant code please.